# how to manually construct a dendrogram from encoded linkage matrix

Tags: python, scipy, cluster-computing, linkage, dendrogram

I have created an encoded linkage matrix using python `scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage` module and exported the data as JSON containing following matrix

```
[[ 1.          5.          0.82352941  2.        ]
[ 4.          7.          0.82857143  2.        ]
[ 9.         11.          0.84313725  2.        ]
[ 6.         14.          0.84883721  3.        ]
[ 2.          8.          0.85714286  2.        ]
[10.         12.          0.86046512  2.        ]
[ 0.         15.          0.87098646  3.        ]
[ 3.         13.          0.87114625  3.        ]
[18.         20.          0.90143223  5.        ]
[17.         21.          0.91183896  7.        ]
[16.         19.          0.91359709  6.        ]
[22.         23.          0.92420979 13.        ]]
```

What is the algorithm for manually constructing a dendrogram, so that i can write code to draw a dendrogram using libraries like D3 from this linkage matrix

Comment: please outline an algorithm to traverse a tree from this data

Comment: Any progress on this problem?